# Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

```
**I trying to use Spring in Intellij.**

**I am getting following error,**
ex Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor
```

### The JAVA code and XML files are below,

`enter code here`

```
package com.getorganized.spring_xml;
public class HelloWorld {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Spring 3 : Hello ! " + name);
    }
}
```

---

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<bean id="helloBean" class="com.getorganized.spring_xml.HelloWorld">
    <property name="name" value="Mkyong" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

### [CLICK HERE for Intellij JAVA External Library Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XmcZ.jpg)

```
enter code here

package com.getorganized.spring_xml;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SpringXmlSalesReportRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringBeans.xml");
            HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBean");
            obj.printHello();*/
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ex " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

---

```
enter code here

POM.XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.getorganized</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaCoffee</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>JavaCoffee</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test-related stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>    
</project>
```

Comment: Do you have the spring core dependency? if you are using maven, I suggest you configure it in the pom and that should fix your problem. Also, it is better you provide as much as information so the community could help you out.

Comment: Thanks Vikram for quick reply.I am using Intellij and have core dependency spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar.I am not using MAVEN in my project.I have added image showing all external library.As you mentioned to use pom I will give a try.

Comment: Hi Vikram I have added pom and MAVEN in my project

Comment: Are you able to run mvn clean install outside intelliJ and run the app?

Comment: Did that work by adding it to maven?

Comment: Hi Vikram Thanks for your suggestion it has solved my issue.